# How to import JS script in vue loader component?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, vue.js

I have a vue-component

**vue-compoennt (vue-loader)**

```
<template>
  <p>This is a template</p>
</template>
<script>
  require('main.js')
  huha()
</script>
```

And I have

**main.js**

```
 var huha = function(){
      alert("this is huha");
    }; 
alert("this is simple alert");
```

Here I get the 'simple alert' but in assessing huha() it is showing reference error. Can someone please help me to understand why is this happening?

**Edit**

I am trying to use testimonial.js as following and I am getting reference error.

```
    <template>
      <p>This is a template</p>
      <div id="testimonial-slider"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
      require('testimonial/testimonial.js')
      require('testimonial/testimonial.css')
      var testimonial = new Testimonial('#testimonial-slider');
    </script>
    <style>
      p{
         color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

It is giving "reference error: Testimonial is not defined"

Comment: Can I see your component code?

Comment: Actually i am using vue-loader webpack in this app.  So in vue-component we write html,  script and style in same file with extension '. vue-component'  so i haven't defined a separate component.  My component is 'vue-component'

Comment: `module.exports` only works with a compilar, like browserify. Whats your build process?

Comment: I am using webpack.  I am also using vue-loader

Answer (score 1):

You need to export a function like so:

```
module.exports = {
    huha: function(){
      return alert("this is huha");
    }
};
```

And then in you components file:

```
<template>
  <p>This is a template</p>
</template>
<script>
  var main = require('main.js')
  main.huha()
</script>
```

Comment: I have done this but it's not working?  I require 'testimonial.js' library so when I do 'require("testimonial")'  then use this libraries functions and objects then reference error is thrown.

Comment: @AshviniKumar
How exactly do you use the library? Every component is scoped. You're probably referencing the library out of scope.

Comment: @YauheniPrakopchyk I have updated the question, Please have a look at the edited version of the question